# Image aspect ratio is just barely different than the image in a new tab

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image inside a container. The image has object-fit contain set to it in order to maintain aspect ratio. It does this, but just shy away from perfect.
When I open the image in a new tab and compare it with the one in my browser, the browser image shows the slightest blurriness compared to the one in the new tab.

I've tried setting max-width, max-height, to the image and all gave the same result. The image dimensions ended up being different by a few decimal points which caused blurriness.
I want the image to be inside the container while maintaining aspect ratio like how it is in a new tab.

HTML

```js
"use strict";

const $ = (selector) => document.querySelector(selector);

const gallery = $(".gallery").childNodes;
const slides = $("#my_modal").childNodes;

$(".gallery").addEventListener("click", evt => {
    for ( let i in gallery ) {
        if ( evt.target == gallery[i] ) {
            $("#my_modal").style.display = "initial";
            slides[i].style.display = "initial";

            $("#my_modal").addEventListener("click", evt => {
                if ( evt.target == $("#my_modal") ) {
                    $("#my_modal").style.display = "none";
                    slides[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
}
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
}
.gallery {
    text-align: center;
}
.gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 360px;
    height: 480px;
    object-fit: cover;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.my_slides {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 90%;
    width: 90%;
    background-color: gray;
}
.my_slides img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="gallery">
        <img src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" alt="">
    </div>

    <div id="my_modal" class="modal">
        <div id="boros1" class="my_slides">
            <img src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is my JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/38rauwnf/
I suggest replicating on your machine in order to see the whole browser and opening the image in a new tab and comparing the images. The blue eyeball will be blurrier than the new tab.

Here is the image in the browser https://i.stack.imgur.com/igjFD.jpg
Here is the image in the new tab https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RhxQ.jpg

EDIT: My problem has been solved on this post [My images are blurry in Chrome but not Firefox w/ video demonstration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69239327/my-images-are-blurry-in-chrome-but-not-firefox-w-video-demonstration)

Comment: is this what you need ? `.my_slides img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position:top center;
}`  https://jsfiddle.net/u3ze1854/

Comment: @G-Cyrillus not quite, I want the image to be shown in its entirety (not clipped) while also maintaining its ratio like how it is when you open the image in a new tab.
The JSFiddle looks perfect with your solution along with my post, but when I replicate it on chrome it becomes blurry. No idea why :/

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Boros?file=Boros+Manga.png

Comment: then, is  `.my_slides img {
    width: 100%;
}`sufficient to not clip the image ?

Comment: That causes it to overflow out of the .my_slides container since the width will be as long as the container causing it to have height auto making it overflow outside. I could add overflow hidden, but that would just clip it. I would like to be able to see the whole image inside the container while maintaining its ratio

Comment: to me it looks fine (as sharp)  , i thought that the probleme was elsewhere , sorry to have wasted your time.

Comment: Not wasted at all. I'm just confused as to why it's not sharp when it should I think. The image _is_ sharp on firefox & working as intended. On chrome the image is blurrier than the one in the new tab, very weird lol.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus here is my video clip showing that the image in chrome is in fact blurry compared to firefox if you're curious https://streamable.com/pwgdau