# My images are blurry in Chrome but not Firefox w/ video demonstration

Tags: html, css

I have an image lightbox that pops out the image when you click on it. Everything works fine except on chrome. When you have the zoom over 80% on Chrome, the image will become blurry. This doesn't happen on Firefox so it doesn't matter what zoom level you have.

Here is my video demonstrating the issue. https://streamable.com/9uv1j1

You can also see the issue if you change the zoom in JSFiddle on Firefox & Chrome https://jsfiddle.net/h8xqe50v/

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="gallery">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/zkxdeCT.jpeg" alt="">
    </div>

    <div id="my_modal" class="modal">
            <div id="boros1" class="my_slides">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/zkxdeCT.jpeg" alt="">
            </div>
    </div>
    <script src="scripts/test.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: black;
}
.gallery {
    text-align: center;
}
.gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 360px;
    height: 480px;
    object-fit: cover;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.my_slides {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: auto;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    background-color: gray;
}
.my_slides img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, apparently Chrome is really bad with preserving quality when downsizing images.

You can add this in your CSS to remove the blur

```
.gallery img {
    /* the rest of your css */
    image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
}
```

Comment: This does fix most of the issue. It seems to make it less blurry not completely sharp. If you set the zoom to 80% you will see that becomes much more sharp. I will accept this answer as it does make it less blurry & it's really not that big of an issue in most cases. Thanks!